# Totals for all fields in a database

Tags: sql

Is there a way to run and SQL query that will return the total for all fields in a database on a field by field basis?

Ideally the query would sum numeric and date fields and count text fields.

i.e.

Table 1

```
Amount1 Amount2  Text1
10        25      AAA
25        50      BBB
30        25      null
```

Results

```
Table1, Amount1 65
Table1, Amount2 100
Table1, Text1  2
```

This would need to repeat for all fields in all tables.

Comment: You'll have to do that dynamically. How exactly would depend on your dbms.

Comment: Additionally, when you say you want to sum date fields, what do you want exactly? For example, what is the sum of `01-01-1999` and `05-05-2016`?

Comment: Tables have columns, not fields...

Answer (score 2):

Use Select with [GROUP BY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms177673(v=sql.120).aspx) clause (group by TABLE_ROW_ID):

```
SELECT SUM(Amount1), SUM(Amount2), COUNT(Text1) FROM Table1 GROUP BY TABLE_ROW_ID
```

Comment: "all fields in a database". This is a solution for a single table, not all fields in a database.

Comment: Thanks for replies so far - this is in SQL Management Studio 2012 - I have some code that uses schema currently to report on total rows for each table in the database so looking for something similar for each column (field). Initially if it could just total up each column for all tables that would be a good start - I can work out what to do with text / date fields later

Answer (score 0):

There is, but will require a use of the INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables, such as TABLES and COLUMNS. Maybe, if you can use T4 for a template of the query and a logic to build query per table. [Here](http://www.olegsych.com/2008/04/t4-template-design-merged-template-class/) is a walk trough on how to create a template for a Merge statement, it may give you ideas on how to adapt it for your particular case.

Assumption here is that we are talking about SQL Server  (INFORMATION_SCHEMA), I am sure that other RDBMS engines also have a metadata stores.

Comment: Thanks for replies so far - this is in SQL Management Studio 2012 - I have some code that uses schema currently to report on total rows for each table in the database so looking for something similar for each column (field). Initially if it could just total up each column for all tables that would be a good start - I can work out what to do with text / date fields later.